# ScheduleWidget (.net core version) cannot build MonthlyByDayOfMonth (3) schedules

Tags: c#, .net-core, schedulewidget

I use [ScheduleWidget](http://schedulewidget.azurewebsites.net/) as the scheduling framework for one of my test .net core web api project. However, I am unable to build monthly schedules as illustrated in the documentation.

ex: MonthlyByDayOfMonth (3) DuringMonth The 24th of each month.

when I try to use this frequency type it seems it requires a WeekInterval. But in my scenario I just wanted to create a schedule which occurs on a particular date on each month. But I don't see any method in the builder to do this.

Consider the following ex: if I uncomment the DuringMonth method it works but it creates a schedule for the first Monday of each month which is not the scenario I'm looking for.

```
 var schedule = builder
            //.DuringMonth(WeekInterval.First)
            .OnDaysOfWeek(DayInterval.Mon)
            .HavingFrequency(FrequencyType.MonthlyByDayOfMonth)
            .Create();
```

Has any one used this framework for creating Monthly schedules for scenarios like 
ex: MonthlyByDayOfMonth (3) DuringMonth The 24th of each month.

Comment: Do you have latest version? (see : https://github.com/jamesstill/ScheduleWidget.Core).  The link you provided says at bottom to make tag schedulewidget.  I will add the tag.  Look at source code and see if you can make the change.

Comment: See pdf document : https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf

Comment: @jdweng yes I have the latest version. I did have a quick look at the source code, it seems this is not supported. I am intended to do the code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was missing from ScheduleWidget.Core. I have added it:

```
Install-Package ScheduleWidget.Core -Version 2.1.1
```

To use:

```
var builder = new ScheduleBuilder();

var schedule = builder
    .OnDayOfMonth(24)
    .HavingFrequency(FrequencyType.DayOfMonth)
    .Create();

var during = new DateRange(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddMonths(6));

foreach (var date in schedule.Occurrences(during))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

I appreciate it Dinindu that you alerted me to this. If there are any other missing scenarios anyone has do let me know.

Comment: Thanks James. Appreciate your prompt response.